# When page request and reload javascript functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project. In the index page I have partial view. When the index page open, my partial view is empty and my all javascript function is working.

But when I do some request from index, my partial view dropdownList is filling but all javascript function is not working. What is the problem?

Example js function is

```
$("#txtNote").keyup(function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        var page = 1;
        var opererand = $("#drpOperation option:selected").text();
        var examTypeId = $("#drpOperation option:selected").val();
        var year = $('#year').val();
        var semesterId = $('#semesterId').val();
        var value = $('#txtNote').val();
        var tree = $('#tree-programs').asTree();
        if (tree.selectedItems.length == 0) {
            alert('Program Seçimi Yapmadınız.');
            return;
        }
        var a = 5;
        //programId = tree.selectedItems[0].id;
        var disciplineId = $('#disciplineListId').val();
        //var disciplines = { "Id": 1, "Name": "white" };

        var examFilter = {

            ExamTypeId: examTypeId,
            Operand: opererand,
            Value: value
        };
        GetList(page, year, semesterId, 1158, disciplineId, examFilter)

    }
}
```

Comment: use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: actually it depends when and where you define your js function , try moving it to jQuery doc ready event and make your input textbox txtNote has been rendered in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,
i had to write like this

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#txtNote', function () {

           //Codes..

});
```

I tried it It works succesfuly.